# PHP: Checking if a date is older then a year

Tags: php

I have a date I'm pulling from my database. I want to check if that date is over a year old.

I have done the following but I'm sure my logic is incorrect.

```
if (strtotime($horsesplaced1['Date']) < strtotime('-1 year')) {
    //true
    $placed .= "/";
    $stopyear = "yes";
}
```

Comment: And your question is?..

Comment: Go and grab yourself a cup of tea, you are doing it right.

Comment: depends on the type of `Date` column. YYYY-MM-DD or unix timestamp?

Answer (score 10):

Try like this:

```
<?
$dbDate = '2014-01-20 17:14:40';
if(strtotime($dbDate)<strtotime('-1 year')){
 echo "YES";
}else{
echo "NOP";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP DateTime is far more useful for this. Something like:

```
$new = new DateTime('2015-01-01');
$old = new DateTime('2013-01-01');

if ( $old->modify('+1 year') < $new) {
    echo "More than a year ago";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the **[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)** functions its much easier to solve such problems.

```
$checkDate = new \DateTime('2013-01-01');

$pastDate = clone $aktDate;
$pastDate->modify('-1 year');

if($checkDate < $pastDate) {
    // Do something
}
```

I don't know if you work with a datetime field/object. If you have a datetime object you can work directly with them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compare using timestamp here.

Do like this:

```
if(strtotime($your_date) < strtotime('-1 year') ){
           echo "Date is older than year";
 }else{
           echo "Date is not older than year";
}
```

`$your_date` should be in `datetime` format.